# asp.net mvc: usersContext.SaveChanges() saves null instead of given values; only on azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, azure

My registration process creates a new user, asks for the id of the newly created user and uses it as key in an table with aditional information like following codes shows:

```
String confirmationToken = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
    model.Email,
    model.Password,
    null,
    true
);

UsersContext usersContext = new UsersContext();
User user = usersContext.Users.First(e => e.Email == model.Email);

PersonalInformation personalInformation = new PersonalInformation() {
    UserID = user.UserID,
    FirstName = model.FirstName,
    LastName = model.LastName
};

usersContext.PersonalInformation.Add(personalInformation);
usersContext.SaveChanges();
```

This works fine on my local machine, but when I publish it on azure. It just creates the user/account but fails with:
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserID', table 'optindb.dbo.PersonalInformation';

When I take a look at the database I can see that the user table is filled with the email and of course the id as primary key.

So my guess is, that "usersContext.Users.First" returns null, but I can't figure out why...
Do I have to do something special with "WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount" so I can sure it is saved to the databse before I ask for the ID?

Any help is welcomed.

---

**edit:**

After reading the comments below this post I took a closer look and sent the value of the "Users.First" value together with the registration mail and found out that it indeed works correct and has the ID value in it.

So the real problem must be in this part:

```
PersonalInformation personalInformation = new PersonalInformation() {
    UserID = user.UserID,
    FirstName = model.FirstName,
    LastName = model.LastName
};

usersContext.PersonalInformation.Add(personalInformation);
usersContext.SaveChanges();
```

The values get set in the personalInformation object, but when saving the usersContext it wants to save a NULL instead of the userID stored in the object. Can't get my head around whats going on here..

Comment: Is your `UserID` an `IDENTITY` on the Azure instance?

Comment: Yes, it says like following:
[UserID] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,

Comment: There you have it. The `UserID` column in the `Users` table is nullable. You're pulling out the `null` value and inserting it into a table that has `NOT NULL` specified on the column..

Comment: But when I take a look at my tables after I tried to register a new account the user table has a record with an given UserID and Email. So it should be able to get that UserID value, shouldn' it?

Comment: All I can say without seeing your code.. is that errors don't lie :) Your error clearly states it cannot put `null` where `null` isn't allowed..

Comment: Okay, thanks so far. I just could imagine the fault was there but with your comments I took another look and found out that the problem has to do with saving the object, not getting the id. Edited my post.